# Custom alerts in elastic search kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

We have elasticsearch along with kibana. Onboard 100's of applications to elastic search and able to see it in kibana. Error, failed transactionThreshold alerts were already cobfigured. NOW i would like to know how to create cutom alerts as per our needs ? What are the standards for it ?

Hello, We have elasticsearch along with kibana. Onboard 100's of applications to elastic search and able to see it in kibana. Error, failed transactionThreshold alerts were already cobfigured. NOW i would like to know how to create cutom alerts as per our needs ? What are the standards for it ? I have tried stack management and rules to create alerts. But i am looking for customized or custom alerts

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to create alert with your data.

- [Watcher](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/how-watcher-works.html): (paid feature, need license)

Watcher is Elasticsearch's native alerting and notification feature. It allows you to create custom alerts based on specific conditions.

- [ElastAlert2](https://elastalert2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): (opensource)

ElastAlert is an open-source alternative for custom alerts in Elasticsearch, offering flexibility and customization. Learn more

- [Kibana Alerting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/alerting-getting-started.html): (this is what you used so far.)

Kibana's alerting framework enables you to create custom alerts within the Kibana interface. Learn more